# creating another list from a list based on value and date [excel]

Tags: excel

I am trying to create an Excel spreadsheet that organizes employees in a company. I would like to create a leave tracker that traces which employee is on leave or on duty. I have managed to create that part, but I cannot create a separate list based on my leave tracker and create another list based on date and where each employee works at.

[image]

The leave tracker is almost done and it is fully working. However, I would like make another tab that says "section info" and sorts each employee's name and informs the user whether the employee is on leave or not based on date. So everytime when i open up the spreadsheet, the result has to be updated every day.

[image]

So, the idea is I want to create a spreadsheet that shows whether the employee is working or taking leaves.

I am not supposed to use any VBA in this project.

Comment: So, In summery when you will open that sheet it will show a list which employees are in leave today?

Comment: Yes also the spreadsheet needs to show which work section each employee on leave belongs to. There are five different sections each employee work at